# Normal Distrubution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am studying Normal Distrubution and stuck at one problem.pls help
quest-If the mean of a normal frequency distribution of 1000 items is 25 and its standard deviation is 2.5, then its maximum ordinate is

Answer (score 1):

The maximum ordinate of a normal distribution is given by $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$.